# Where is Groff formatter?

Tags: software-installation

I am a new Ubuntu user. My default text formatter on Windows is Wingroff, a `GNU roff` port.

I have installed the complete Ubuntu system from the 14.04 install disk, but I cannot locate `groff`: not on the default installation nor on the Ubuntu listing
of downloadbale packages. How can I install it?

Answer (score 2):

Groff can be found and installed from the Ubuntu Software Center - open the program and type 'groff'

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you run apt-get update before attempting to install.

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install groff

This worked for me on 14.04